# Rust pretty print with alignment

Tags: rust, pretty-print

Like `{:0>6}` for alignment of a normal debug or display print, is there a way to align a pretty print with `{:#?}` in Rust?

Tried:

```rust
println!("{:#?0>6}", 123);
```

Expected the output:

```
000123
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just have to use the correct [syntax as specified in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#syntax):

> ```
> [[fill]align][sign]['#']['0'][width]['.' precision]type
> ```

i.e. `#` has to come after `>` wihch is your `align` and before `6` which is your `width` and the `type` (`?` for `Debug`) has to come last.

So for your example that would be:

```
println!("{:0>#6?}", 123);
```

Comment: Thank you @cafce25. It would be nice to provide an example for each of the options "fill", "align", "sign" etc. Does all the options come after : ?
I need to go through the doc.
I have tried {:0>#6?} and it worked as expected.

Comment: That's already in the documentation: `format := '{' [ argument ] [ ':' format_spec ] [ ws ] * '}'` so yes the `format_spec` as outlined above always comes after the `:`